# How to implement pagination in PowerBI to fetch all data/issues from Jira (not only the 50 maxResults)?

Tags: powerbi, jira-rest-api

I am using PowerBI to create a dashboard of issues written in Jira. I am using an API to get the data from Jira, but they limited the # of results to 50. How can I paginate the data in PowerBI to get all issues, or let's say, 3000 issues.
I can get the 50 issues without any problem, but cannot retrieve the rest. Can you help me, please?

Comment: The query I use is https://myjirainstance/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20=%20myproject%20AND%20issuetype%20=%20"IssueType"%20%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC&startAt=0&maxResults=50. If I set the "startAt" parameter to 50, I can get the next 50 results. My question is if this can be done automatically (having the startat parameter increase by 50 per call) within the Power Query Editor of PowerBI, until the total results are fetched.